# Block Access to XenApp by Client ID/Name

Tags: xenapp

Is it possible to block access to all published applications, desktops, and content on a XenApp 6.0 farm for a list of client names? If so how would this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to achieve? What is the reason for blocking some clients?

Applications are published on a user basis and the client does not matter. If user "A" has rights to start the application "notepad" he can start it on "every" client.
The problem is you can only allow someone to start an app and not deny.

There is a possibility to "block" an IP-range. You can create a load evaluator with a specific IP-Range and set it to deny.

You can also add a citrix policy with a session-limit of 0 and set a filter with the clientnames.

Both methods allow the user to see the published apps. In the first method he gets a message that the server load is exceeded in the second one that he is not allowed to have more than 0 sessions.